Load balacing in Kubernetes: Ingress controllers concept
I am new to Kubernetes and intend to study and understand various forms of load balancing in Kubernetes. I came across many articles mentioning Ingress controller and have been trying myself to use one.
What I thought I could do was to install an ingress controller (nginx/haproxy) and test internal load balancing. From my research people only seem to use ingress controllers to connect to external load balancers (by cloud providers, i.e. aws or gke). I also read that when load balancing with this external load balancers has "two layers" of load balancing which would be the load balancing to the nodes of the cluster done by the external load balancer, and the load balancing among the pods of a service that would be done by the ingress and that makes me think that I can test internal oad balancing with only an ingress controller.
I wanted to know if it was possible to do that or if I am not understanding these concepts correctly and how they are applied in reality.
For reference, I have a cluster running on vagrant nodes and have tried to install and configure an ingress controller but with no success, since there is no external IP being assigned to the ingress.
I can give details on what I've implemented, but I really think that I have hit a conceptual wall for now.

I am assuming you are using the Kubernetes the Hard Way setup and have already set up your control plane master and worker nodes with tools like kubeadm. It's important to note that Kubernetes the Hard Way automatically deploys a load balancing node for internal load balancing within the cluster.
Given this setup, you can indeed utilize an Ingress controller for internal load balancing. While Ingress controllers are commonly associated with external load balancing, they are also capable of handling internal traffic routing within the cluster.
The "two layers" concept you mentioned relate to the external load balancer directing traffic to nodes and the Ingress controller managing traffic among pods of a service internally.
LB Node vs Ingress Controller:
Load Balancing Node: Handles internal traffic within the cluster, acting as a layer 4 load balancer.
Ingress Controller: Manages external access to services and can also handle internal traffic routing, acting as a layer 7 load balancer.
To test internal load balancing with an Ingress controller in your Vagrant-based Kubernetes the Hard Way setup:

Confirm that your control plane master, worker nodes, and load
balancing node are operational.
Install and configure an Ingress controller such as Nginx or
HAProxy.
Define Ingress resources to specify how internal traffic should be
routed to services and pods.
Ingress controllers use these Ingress resources to configure
internal load balancing rules.
Use ClusterIPs or the load balancing node's IP for internal
communication as external IPs may not be assigned in this setup.

You can always refer to the k8s docs which has all info related to ingress controllers and kubernetes in general.

Thank you for your answer!
So I need to have a single node inside the cluster to be the load balancer? And how do I install a load balancer on that node? Is MetalLB a possible solution? What are other options? If the load balancer is inside the cluster, what is the difference in having a specific node for it if the pods will be running on any of the nodes of the cluster?
If externalIPs cannot be assigned in this setup how can I reach my web server from the browser as I did before?

Depending on your case, it's not a must to have a node that only acts as a load balancer, it is just for Kubernetes the hard way which aims to let you setup everything in the cluster "the hard way" to distribute traffic across your local VMs. And yes metalLB is a good choice if you prefer setting up your ingress controller yourself and not rely on cloud providers loadbalancers. With metalLB you end up allocating service IPs yourself using a configmap for instance. A dedicated load balancer node isolates resources for optimized performance.

It's important to note that the node load balancer, similar to kube-proxy, involves using a specific node for load balancing tasks but may require external solutions for IP assignment and routing traffic within the cluster. MetalLB can serve the external solution needed.
